# Can I configure MacOS to open CSV and Excel files in Google Sheets?

Tags: macos, google-spreadsheets

Is there a way to have MacOS open CSV and Excel files in Google Sheets when you double-click them? I've tried associating the Google Sheets shortcut in Applications but that doesn't work.

Comment: While this question mentions Google Sheets it doesn't look to be appropriate for [webapps.se]. Maybe [apple.se]. Have you installed Google Drive (formerly Backup & Sync / File stream) ? Also please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install the [Office Editing for Docs, Sheets & Slides](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/office-editing-for-docs-s/gbkeegbaiigmenfmjfclcdgdpimamgkj) Chrome Extension and then register the file types that you want to open with Chrome. You can use either Finder or SwiftDefaultApps.

**Using Finder**

You have to do this once per file extension you want to associate:

1. Select a file (ie, `some-sheet.xlsx`) in Finder
2. Press `⌘` + `i`
3. Change the `Open with:` option to `Google Chrome.app`
4. Click `Change All...`
5. Now all your `.xlsx` will open with Chrome
6. Repeat for other file types (see [supported file types](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6055139?p=ocm_intro&visit_id=637626007900459615-2601308057&rd=2#zippy=%2Cfile-types-you-can-open-with-ocm))

**Using [SwiftDefaultApps](https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/SwiftDefaultApps)**

You can install using `brew install swiftdefaultappsprefpane --cask`. It installs as a *Pref Panel*, meaning you will find it in System Preferences.

More instructions on how to use it are available on the [readme](https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/SwiftDefaultApps#readme).

Comment: thank you for this! Did not know about the office extension The default Apple Numbers app is a piece of crap.

Comment: Great tip, if using duti you can add this to your duti file:

```
com.google.Chrome xls all
com.google.Chrome xlsx all
com.google.Chrome xlb all
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://support.google.com/docs/thread/3884278/how-do-i-set-up-google-sheets-as-my-default-when-i-download-from-outside-sources-such-as-banks?hl=en, you can install a Chrome extension that handles Office-like files in Google's web-apps.  Then, just associate the extensions that you want (CSV, XLSX, etc.) with Chrome.